# Converting values in a Pandas column based to a string name on their ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas column called 'Age' that consists of float values from 0 all the way to 100. I would like to convert numerical data to strings based on predefined ranges. Below you'll see a dictionary where the key is the value that will be used to replace the column value and the dictionary value (1, 6, 12, etc.) is used to define the various ranges. I.e., the conditions for the if statements would be `column_value < 1`, `column_value < 6` etc

```
ranges = {'baby': 1, 'toddler': 6, 'kid': 12, 'teen': 21, 'adult': 80, 'old': 1000}
```

I am aware that one can probably do this by iterating over each row within the column, but this isn't very sufficient, especially if there are many conditions. I am using the following code but am running into data types problems, specifically comparing a string to a float. My code is shown below:

```
def to_range(df, col, ranges):
    # iterate over the dictionary by converting all column values that are less than the specified range to the given range name

    for key, value in ranges.items():
        df.loc[(df[col].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, float)) == True) & 
               (df[col] < value), col] = key
        
    return df  

ranges = {'baby': 1, 'toddler': 6, 'kid': 12, 'teen': 21, 'adult': 80, 'old': 1000}
column_name = 'Age'

to_range(testdf, column_name, ranges)
```

I understand that having a column with mixed values isn't ideal but is there any way to achieve what I am wanting to do? I feel that I am missing something obvious.

Example of a before and after of what I am trying to achieve:

| Age | Output Age |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | toddler |
| 82 | old |
| 15 | teen |
| 9 | kid |
| 25 | adult |

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest in addition to the table at the bottom of the post?

Comment: you mentioned that you are running "into data types problems": what's your `testdf['Age'].dtype` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Initially it is float, but as soon as I make the first change (eg: changing all values <1 to baby) the column becomes type object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
ranges = {'baby': 1, 'toddler': 6, 'kid': 12,
          'teen': 21, 'adult': 80, 'old': 1000}

# get the labels in the order of ages
labels = sorted(ranges, key=ranges.get)
# ['baby', 'toddler', 'kid', 'teen', 'adult', 'old']

# get bins
bins = [0] + [ranges[x] for x in labels]
# [0, 1, 6, 12, 21, 80, 1000]

df['Output Age'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

If the dictionary is already sorted by increasing ages:

```
labels, bins = zip(*ranges.items())

df['Output Age'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=(0,)+bins, labels=labels)
```

Output:

```
   Age Output Age
0    2    toddler
1   82        old
2   15       teen
3    9        kid
4   25      adult
```

Or for fun, using a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
pd.merge_asof(df.reset_index().sort_values(by='Age'),
              pd.Series(ranges).rename_axis('Output Age').reset_index(name='Age'),
              on='Age', direction='forward'
             ).set_index('index').reindex(df.index)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How would the solution change if I didn't want to provide a value for the last variable? i.e the value 1000 for 'old'. In this context say we want anything > 80 to be classified as "old". Could this be done or would one always have to provide a "large" number (i.e. 1000 in this case)?

Comment: Then use `float('inf')` as limit